# PHPExcel generates rubbish

Tags: phpexcel

I am trying to generate Excel document using PHPExcel library.

```
class product_specification_order extends DBHelper
{
    static $PK = 'orderID';

    static function xls($id){
       require_once('../lib/PHPExcel.php');
       $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
       $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
       return $objPHPExcel;
    }
 }
```

Then, I have generatespecxls.php file

```
if (empty($_REQUEST['id']))
    die("Wrong ID");
//output xls

header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");;
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=File.xls");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

$objPHPExcel = product_specification_order::xls($_REQUEST['id']);
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($objPHPExcel);    //  (I want the output for objWriter)
///print_r($objWriter);
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

The output I get is rubbish.

Comment: Please define "Rubbish". A BIFF Excel file is a binary stream of data that might look like rubbish to a human being, but is meaningful to MS EXcel

Comment: And please use the correct content-type (application/vnd.ms-excel) rather than three different (and wrong) content types

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried different content types and that did not help. By rubbish I mean unreadable characters in the resulting XLS. There is no other output, so the issue should be in the XLS generation itself or the way it is streamed

Comment: The only output you should get from PHPExcel should be readable in MS Excel.... with the right headers (e.g. those used in the examples such as 01simple-download-xls.php) it should prompt a user with an open/save dialogue box in the browser